# Is there a way to "store" an Amazon S3 request and use it elsewhere? (JavaScript SDK)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to generate an S3 GET request using the JavaScript SDK, and then take that HTTP request and execute is from another machine using CURL.

Is this possible?  Note that I am aware of pre-signed requests but I want a solution that is more secure than that.  Specifically I want to be able to use requests that provide auth information in request headers.

So somehow theoretically I would "build" the S3 request using the JavaScript SDK then grab the request URL and headers and run them elsewhere.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but I have to point out that using the query string is not, in any meaningful sense, less secure than using the `Authorization` header.  Obscure != secure.

Comment: @Michael a query string, if capture passing over the Internet by a proxy or observed by something that "sees" URLs can simply be picked up and replayed.  Requests that contain a URL and auth information in headers are much more secure because two pieces of information are required to access  the URL, and headers are not captured by proxies or server logs.

Comment: A proxy cannot capture the URL when you are using HTTPS unless It is forging SSL certificates and the client has installed a CA cert that allows it to trust the proxy's forged certificates.  The URL is sent inside the encrypted connection.  When not using HTTPS, a proxy *should* be capturing and storing the request headers, because they're required for correct cache behavior.  The reverse proxies in my network also log the most common request headers.

Comment: @michael.... hmmm for a supposedly fairly expert level web application developer I think I should have known this already.